# Adding objects to a ListView row at runtime

Tags: android

I am trying to add elements to a ListView dynamically at runtime. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/category_row"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- Contents will be added at Runtime -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The getView function overridden by my adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View searchResultsRow = convertView;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TextView e1,e2,e3,e4;
        if (searchResultsRow == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            searchResultsRow = layoutInflator.inflate(
                    R.layout.categories_row_object, null);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) searchResultsRow.findViewById(R.id.category_row);

        }
        e1 = new TextView(context);
        e2 = new TextView(context);
        e3 = new TextView(context);
        e4 = new TextView(context);

        e1 = new TextView(context);
        e1.setText("Fashion");
        linearLayout.addView(e1);

        e2 = new TextView(context);
        e2.setText("Men");
        linearLayout.addView(e2);

        e3 = new TextView(context);
        e3.setText("Casual Wear");
        linearLayout.addView(e3);


        e4 = new TextView(context);
        e4.setText("Jeans");
        linearLayout.addView(e4);


        return searchResultsRow;
    }
```

Now what happens that the first couple of rows seem at jumbled up. Like multiple rows have been added to the same row. What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: searchResultsRow is reused, therefore it contains all the items you have already added to it the previous time you used it.

Comment: so what should i so then ?

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if ConvertView != null, linearLayout is not initialed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `convertView`, if not null, is a previously used view, already containing the 4 `TextViews`.

What you have to do is reuse the existing `TextViews` from `convertView`.

One way of doing this is as so: you are inflating `categories_row_object`. Put your 4 `TextView` in it, then access it by id.

Or, you could browse the children views of your `LinearLayout`.